# WCF Endpoint Exception when testing on server

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction as pulling what little hair I have left out ;0(.

I have picked up a someone's vb.net project but have very little experience in WCF and I'm getting a problem when trying to get it running on a server.

I'm hosting on IIS for both testing locally and on the server machine.

If I run locally on my machine then I can commutate with the service fine and everything works as it should however I have now setup IIS with this service on a server to test and I get the following error when looking in event viewer.

**Error:** Endpoint Exception information:

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: Service 'InterfaceServiceHost.InterfaceService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.
```

I have searched around and looked at several post recommending things to look at but just can't seem to find what's wrong.

web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="InterfaceServiceHost.Service1Behavior"
        name="InterfaceServiceHost.InterfaceService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttpBinding_InterfaceService"  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingBinding"
      contract="InterfaceServiceHost.IInterfaceService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="InterfaceServiceHost.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentInstances="256" maxConcurrentSessions="40"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Information displayed on server web browser:**

```
http://localhost/InterfaceServiceHost/interfaceService.svc
```

You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

```
svcutil.exe http://xxxxx.xxx.local/InterfaceServiceHost/InterfaceService.svc?wsdl

Class Test
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim client As InterfaceServiceClient = New InterfaceServiceClient()
        ' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.
        ' Always close the client.
        client.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure about the App pool under which the WCF service is running on IIS.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment - the app pool and project are both framework version 2

Comment: Can you navigate to IIS on the server and right click on .svc file then select browse to see if the service page opens up in the browser  without any problems. Also can you post the interface and the implementation of IInterfaceService.

Comment: Just tried again if I browse to the .svc file in IIS and browse the service page comes up fine without problems (posted those details above) I will grab the other bits you want and post.

Comment: Just to cross check you have tested for the service and it comes up fine in a browser on the server where you have the problem as specified above

Comment: yes that's correct it comes up fine in a browser on the server which is having the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also does the wsdl come up fine in the browser when you click on the wsdl link. If that is the case you should not have any problem accessing the WCF service from the client

Comment: Yes if I click on the wsdl link within that browser window it shows a listing of the interfaceService with the corresponding operation names.

Comment: Is the namespace used in your server code InterfaceServiceHost?  Does it match with what is specified in the .svc file?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is. But not entirely sure I'm looking at the right areas though. Sorry the lack of experience with this.  <%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="InterfaceServiceHost.InterfaceService" CodeBehind="InterfaceService.svc.vb" %>

Answer (score 0):

can you try by giving some value for address

```
<endpoint address="<YOUR SERVICE ADDRESS>" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttpBinding_InterfaceService"  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingBinding"
```

Comment: HI thanks for the reply I have tried "http://localhost/InterfaceServiceHost/interfaceService" and that doesn't make any difference. So is that the correct path to be using based on above? thanks in advance

Comment: hi @ChrisNurse, in one of the above comments u have said that the service is running on a app pool which is targeting .NET framework 2.0, are u sure about that?

Comment: yep I have just checked again and my service is pointing to a TestingAppPool I created which is configured to .NET framework 2.0

Comment: if i am not wrong you have developed your wcf service application chosing .NET framework 4.0, i am guessing so because the address field in endpoint is blank from WCF 4.0 onwards, and its called as simplified configuration. check the likn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx

Comment: I am wrong, as all the way through this process I have taken the original setup on the guy's that left machine who wrote this as a basis to work from. He had the service pool set up to .NET framework 2 so just assumed. But just looked at the project properties to check what it's complied up with and its .NET framework 3.5.

Comment: But again It does run locally using the app pool with .NET framework 2 set?